# Scala: Convert heterogeneous Tuple to List

Tags: scala, types, type-inference

On the Scala command line, there is no problem writing:

```
List((1,2),(1,'a'))
```

But I can't seem to write a function that would convert a `Tuple2` to a `List`, because `Tuple2` takes 2 type parameters, but `List` only one. Any attempt such as:

```
def tuple2ToList[T1, T2](pair: (T1, T2)): List[Any] = List(pair._1, pair._2)
```

seems to be bound to lose type information. Is there anything we can do to preserve some type information in the process?

Comment: `List((1,2),(1,'a'))` also looses type information.

Answer (score 2):

*This is a solution proposed by @BenReich in a comment*

Simply use one type parameter instead of two, the compiler will 
automatically select the least upper bound of the types of the two
tuple elements:

```
def tupleToList[T](p: (T, T)): List[T] = List(p._1, p._2)
```

Examples:

```
scala> tupleToList((Some(42), None))
res4: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(42), None)

scala> tupleToList((0.9999, 1))
res5: List[AnyVal] = List(0.9999, 1)

scala> tupleToList((Set(1), List(1)))
res6: List[scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] with Int => AnyVal] = List(Set(1), List(1))
```

---

*This is the old suboptimal solution, I'll leave it here as context for @BenReich's comment.*

Define the return type as the least upper bound of `T1` and `T2`:

```
def tupleToListRescueTypeInfo[R, T1 <: R, T2 <: R](p: (T1, T2)): List[R] = 
  List(p._1, p._2)
```

Little test:

```
scala> tupleToListRescueTypeInfo((2, 3))
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3)

scala> tupleToListRescueTypeInfo((Some[Int](3), None))
res1: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(3), None)

scala> tupleToListRescueTypeInfo((List(1,2), Set(1,2)))
res2: List[scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] with Int => AnyVal] = 
  List(List(1, 2), Set(1, 2))
```

It obviously cannot preserve all type information, but it at least attempts to rescue as much as possible.

Comment: Why not simply `def tupToList[T](p: (T, T)): List[T] = List(p._1, p._2)`?  The compiler can determine the least upper bound here automatically for your test cases with a simpler method signature.

Comment: @BenReich indeed! Thank you for pointing that out. Would you mind converting your comment into an answer? Then I could remove the suboptimal solution here. Otherwise, if you consider the matter to be too trivial, I could copy-paste your comment into my answer and declare it a community wiki...